# Dell inspiron 3421's wifi is not working on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wireless

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on my dell 3421 laptop but my wifi is not working. It is showing it has a  proprietary driver, how do I get it to work?

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your PC to mobile phone(connected wifi or mobile data) and turn on USB tethering. Then run "**sudo apt-get update**" and install "**Additional Driver**" in the software center if don't have installed. Then find your wireless driver in "**Additional Driver**" and install it. This way solved for my dell.

Comment: I do not recommend installing additional driver until we know for sure that is the driver you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it was no longer going to software and updates, then click into additional drivers and finally here you must choose the option which says Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA .....

Regards